# route endpoint conflicts when generating sphinx doc for flask restful api

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to build documentation for a Flask webapp that includes a REST-like API built into it.  I'm using sphinx, specifically the [httpdomain](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/) extension from sphinxcontrib, using the **autohttp.flask** module to auto-generate my Flask docs, and the **autohttp.qrefflask** module to auto-generate a quick reference table to go along with it.  However, when I try to build my sphinx docs (`make html`), I'm running into the error of conflicting route endpoints

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/Users/../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1051, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: api.View1:add_config
```

I only really care about generating documentation for my API and none of the Flask web routes, so I've restricted my sphinx documentation to only build the api blueprints.  Here is my sphinx `api.rst`

```
.. qrefflask:: myapp.web:create_app(debug=True)
   :undoc-static:
   :endpoints:
   :blueprints: api
   :order: path

.. autoflask:: myapp.web:create_app(debug=True)
   :undoc-static:
   :endpoints:
   :blueprints: api
   :order: path
```

My Flask app and Blueprint layout is as follows:

```
myapp/
   api/
     __init__.py (api blueprint defined here)
     view1.py
     view2.py
     view3.py
   web/
     __init__.py (main Flask app created here via create_app)
```

I'm wondering if it's a problem with how I'm registering the blueprint, and that sphinx somehow is registering it twice, but I don't understand it.

My `api.__init__.py` basically has my Blueprint definition and a few custom error handlers:

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
theapi = Blueprint("api", __name__, url_prefix='/myapp/api')

@theapi.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(err):
    messages = {'error': 'internal_server_error',
                'message': err.description,
                'traceback': get_traceback(asstring=True)}
    return jsonify({
        'api_error': messages,
    }), 500
```

while my main Flask app creation, `web.__init__.py` just imports this and registers everything:

```
def create_app(debug=False, local=False):

    from myapp.api import theapi as api
    from myapp.api.view1 import View1
    ... 

    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/myapp/static')

    ...

    View1.register(api)
    app.register_blueprint(api)

    return app
```

If I move the api blueprint definition and error_handlers into the main app creation, everything works fine.  But then that breaks the modularity of it.  I'd like to keep my api stuff inside the api module.  Also, if remove either the main **autoflask** or **qrefflask** generation, and only use one, everything works fine. But I'd really like to have the quick reference guide.  The code itself runs fine, but the damn documentation is failing to build.  Does anyone have any suggestions?